# Minimal Maximum $m$-sum

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $m\leq n$. Let $\sigma$ be any rearrangement of $1,2,\dots,n$, then define a $m$-sum of $\sigma$ to be a sum of $m$ consecutive numbers in the list. Define $g_m(\sigma)$ to be the maximum $m$-sum of $\sigma$, then define $f(n,m)$ be the minimal $g_m(\sigma)$ across all $\sigma$. What can we say about $f(n,m)$?

For example, let $n\geq3$ and $\sigma$ be $1,2,3,4,5$, then the $3$-sums of $\sigma$ are $1+2+3,2+3+4,3+4+5$, or $6,9,12$, and $g_3(\sigma)=12$. My program shows that $f(5,3)=8$ with the permutation $5,2,1,4,3$.

Now the question is to find a "simple" expression for $f(n,m)$.

Here is some fairly easy observations.

1. Trivially $f(n,n)=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ and $f(n,1)=n$.
2. We can show that $f(n,2)=n+1$. For any permutation $\sigma$, $n$ must be next to a positive integer, and this gives a $2$-sum of $\sigma$ that is at least $n+1$ so $g_2(\sigma)\geq n+1$ for all $\sigma$ and thus $f(n,2)\geq n+1$. Now by looking at the permutation $n,1,n-1,2,n-2,3,\dots$, we see that the minimum $2$-sum is exactly $n+1$.
3. $f(n,n-1)=\frac12n^2-\frac12n+1$. $n$ has to be in a $(n-1)$-sum, and then the smallest we can make the remaining numbers to be is $1,2,\dots,n-2$, leaving out $n-1$, and this shows that $g_{n-1}(\sigma)\geq1+2+\cdots+n-2+n=\frac12n^2-\frac12n+1$ for all $\sigma$ and thus $f(n,n-1)\geq\frac12n^2-\frac12n+1$. Then the two $(n-1)$-sums of the permutation $n-1,1,2,\dots,n-2,n$ are $\frac12n(n-1)$ and $\frac12n(n-1)+1=\frac12n^2-\frac12n+1$, so we see that $f(n,n-1)$ is exactly $\frac12n^2-\frac12n+1$.
4. $f(n,n-2)=\frac12n^2-\frac32n+3$. Again, $n$ has to be in a $(n-2)$-sum, and the smallest we can make the remaining numbers to be is $1,2,\dots,n-3$, leaning out $n-1,n-2$, and this shows that $g_{n-2}(\sigma)\geq\frac12(n-2)(n-3)+n$ for all $\sigma$ so $f(n,n-2)\geq\frac12(n-2)(n-1)+n$. The three $(n-2)$-sums of the permutation $n,n-3,n-4,\dots,2,1,n-1,n-2$ are $\frac12(n-2)(n-3)+n$, $\frac12(n-2)(n-3)+n-1$ and $\frac12(n-2)(n-3)+n-1$. Therefore $f(n,n-2)=\frac12(n-2)(n-3)+n=\frac12n^2-\frac32n+3$.

However, for $f(n,n-3)$ we can no longer just leave out $n-1,n-2,n-3$. Using a python program, I found out that
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & f(n,n-3) & \sigma \\ \hline
 6 & 11 & 6, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2 \\ \hline
 7 & 15 & 7, 5, 2, 1, 6, 4, 3 \\ \hline
 8 & 20 & 8, 6, 3, 2, 1, 7, 5, 4 \\ \hline
 9 & 26 & 9, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 6, 5 \\ \hline
 10 & 33 & 10, 8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 7, 6 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Of course, the $\sigma$ that gives the minimal $g_m(\sigma)$ is not unique, since you can just simply reverse the permutation. Here I choose the largest permutation with dictionary order.

So the optimal solution seems to be $n,n-2,n-5,n-6,\dots,2,1,n-1,n-3,n-4$ and gives $f(n,n-3)=\frac12n^2-\frac52n+8$. Moreover this only works for $n\geq6$ and not $n=5$. For $f(n,n-4)$ the optimal solution seems to be $n,n-1,n-6,n-7,\dots,1,n-2,n-3,n-4,n-5$ which gives $f(n,n-4)=\frac12n^2-\frac72n+14$, and this only works for $n\geq7$ and not $n=6$. It seems like by doing something similar for $f(n,n-1)$ and $f(n,n-2)$ there is always a simple formula for $f(n,n-a)$ when $n$ is large.

If we try to find a formula for $f(n,3)$, the situation is much more strange. Using the same python code, I found out that
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & f(n,3) & \sigma \\ \hline
3 & 6      & 3,2,1  \\ \hline
 4 & 7      & 4, 2, 1, 3 \\ \hline
 5 & 8      & 5, 2, 1, 4, 3 \\ \hline
 6 & 11     & 6, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2 \\ \hline
 7 & 12     & 7, 4, 1, 6, 3, 2, 5 \\ \hline
 8 & 13     & 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 2, 6, 5 \\ \hline
 9 & 15     & 9, 5, 1, 8, 4, 3, 7, 2, 6 \\ \hline
 10 & 16    & 10, 5, 1, 9, 4, 3, 8, 2, 6, 7 \\ \hline
\end{array}

A few observations: $n$ is always at position $1$ and $1$ is always at position $3$.
Moreover, the numbers at position $1,4,7,\dots$ always appear to be $n,n-1,n-2,\dots$, and if we assume this we can make the program run much faster:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & f(n,3) & \sigma \\ \hline
11 & 18 & 11,6,1,10,5,3,9,4,2,8,7 \\ \hline
 12 & 20 & 12,7,1,11,6,3,10,5,4,9,2,8 \\ \hline
 13 & 21 & 13,7,1,12,6,3,11,5,4,10,2,8,9 \\ \hline
 14 & 22 & 14,7,1,13,5,4,12,6,3,11,8,2,10,9 \\ \hline
 15 & 25 & 15,9,1,14,8,3,13,7,5,12,6,4,11,10,2 \\ \hline
 16 & 26 & 16,9,1,15,8,3,14,7,5,13,6,4,12,10,2,11 \\ \hline
\end{array}

There is one more pattern: the numbers at positions congruent to $1$ modulo $3$ are always greater than the numbers at positions congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, which are in turns greater than the numbers at positions congruent to $0$ modulo $3$. So these three sets of positions roughly contain the largest $1/3$, the middle $1/3$, and the smallest $1/3$ of the numbers. However, these are all just speculations and I don't really have the proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but should give you a good basis for exploring your interesting idea.

I've looked at $f(n,3)$ when $n$ is a multiple of 3. The total of all the numbers is $$\frac{1}{2}n(n+1).$$
Splitting these up into their successive blocks of three numbers shows that a lower bound for $f(n,3)$ is given by the ceiling function for $$\frac{3}{2}(n+1).$$
This bound appears to be attained. This, in fact, agrees with your results except for $n=15$. You give $25$, but the bound given by the ceiling function is $24$ and this is actually attained for
$$15,8, 1,13,9,2,11,3,10,5,7,12,4,6,14.$$

To prove that a given lower bound is attained simply requires an algebraic demonstration.

**For example - Proof for $n=6k$**

The numbers can be arranged as shown, where the centre of the list is marked:-

$$6k,3k,1,...,5k+1,2k+1,2k-1||2k,3k+1,4k+1, ..., 2,4k,5k.$$

The pattern here is that as you move 3 places out from the centre you change the number by $-2,+1,+1,-2, +1,+1,-2,...$.

A quick check should show that the min-max is $9k+2$.

**A general lower bound**

In general, a lower bound for $f(n,m)$ can be found by splitting numbers up into  successive blocks of $m$ numbers with an additional smaller block if $m$ is not a factor of $n$.